# Use VSCode Language specific settings for .min.js

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code [Version 1.10](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10) adds the ability to specify languages settings on a per language basis (*1). You put something like this in your *settings.json* file:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.fontSize": 100,
}
```

I'd like to do something more specific. I'd like to apply different rules to files that match ****.min.js***.

**How would I do that?**

I've actually got something that works, but it's a bit hacky, so I thought I'd ask.

---

*1) In case you want to know which ones: Use autocomplete after typing in `"[]":`, or [see languageIds array in this file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/7f74aa57b0ae21ef2565c0b424960bffe368bc9e/extensions/theme-seti/icons/vs-seti-icon-theme.json).

I'm aware beautify skips formatting min files by default. But just using `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` this doesn't seem to happen. Also, other non-formatting stuff like wordwrap is nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my current solution:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.min.js": "javascriptreact"
},
// Hijack javascriptreact to create custom settings for min.js files
"[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on"
}
```

I'm using the fact that vscode happens to have a second type of javascript, one that isn't used my my project. Not ideal, but it seems to work.